# How to attach Zeikos extension tube to D5100?

Tags: lens, nikon, macro, nikon-d5100, extension-tubes

How to attach the Zeikos macro extension tube to Nikon D 5100 and to the kit lens 18-55mm?
Neither side of the tube seems to fit the body of the camera nor the lens. Perhaps I bought the wrong item for my camera and lens?
Any help to fit these onto the camera and lens would be appreciated. I have attached the pics of the lens, and both sides of the extension tubes. Kindly tell which side will attach to which side of the lens and camera. (note: I donot have the manual)

[Zeikos extension tube on amazon](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B003IVZVDO)

[image: Lens]

[image: Extension tube side 1]

[image: Extension tube side 2]

Comment: in particular it seems to me that the rectangular built of the one side of the tube is a misfit in the built of the camera body shape which is circular...

Comment: The rectangular hole is not the problem. As the image sensor is rectangluar, the hole lets through all the light that goes to the sensor. Actually it's a positive feature, as it will mask off some of the stray light that would otherwise bounce around inside the camera and reduce the contrast.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It appears that you have received the Canon EF-mount tube set, not the Nikon F (AF) version. The contacts and alignment aids are where you'd expect them for Canon EF, and the pass-through screw drive for Nikon AF is missing. Not surprising, then, that it won't fit your Nikon gear.